# Pull comments field from approval process to detail page layout

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to pull comments field from approval history to detail page layout..If not any alternative solution ..The basic idea is to show comments on the detail page layout for a record .

Comment: Easiest way is to add the related list to the page layout....Training users to look there will save you a lot of unnecessary work

Comment: Thnks Eric. .is there a way to pull out the field. .apart from the the related list..

Comment: Yea, you can do it via apex and show the latest comment but again, a lot of work for no gain. tech the users to use the platform whoever possible. The information is already there. Not all requests are reasonable, maybe this one is, only you/they can decide that.

Comment: Can u share how to achieve that..Will be really helpful

Comment: Sure - Write code to grab the field and put it on the main object. You may have to do a batch or a trigger (set a field in the approval process to fire the trigger)

Comment: What if there are more than one comment in the related list?

Comment: thats for you to decide....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31127/discussion-between-raju-sen-and-eric).